# Where clause in Vertica

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, teradata, vertica

I am trying to convert a Vertica view definition to Teradata. I encountered a where clause in Vertica which goes like

`Where ( ColumnA or ColumnB);`

I am not sure how this works as there is no comparison.

Any Ideas  ??

Comment: Are those columns defined as `boolean` in Vertica (if it supports that datatype)?

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to

```
WHERE ColumnA = TRUE OR ColumnB = TRUE
```

assuming both columns are or are coercible to boolean. (Vertica's documentation, which I don't have handy, contains a chart of permissible type coercions; check it out.)

Comment: There's no BOOLEAN datatype in Teradata.